# how to run GTA vice city using wine in ubuntu?

Tags: wine, games, winetricks

I use Ubuntu 18.04 , 64 bit . 
I want to play GTA Vice City using wine.
Wine is installed and is being shown in Ubuntu software..but while opening GTA .exe file , wine is not visible there.
so please help me how to play GTA vice city using wine in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If .exe file can't  be run if you click then open your terminal `ctrl + Alt + T` and roll over to the file location where the .exe file located. Run this command `wine <your-app-name>.exe`. If there is any problem to run the app it will show that, fix the error (if exist) and you are good to go.